# How to debug the 401 error of ASP.NET 4.6 WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working on a web api project which is secured by Azure AD endpoint v2.0. However, I get tons of 401 errors, even I copy the code from the working examples for Github.

My question is **how can I debug the 401 error** in a  most efficient way? As there is little information for the error message:

```
{
  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to dig into the details of exactly what is being sent and received, when.

Have you made sure the user you're attempting to authenticate with does not have multifactor authentication enabled? You'll get 401's for seemingly no reason if MFA is enabled and you try to auth programmatically. If you have already disabled it, post up your auth code here and we'll take a close look.